# Some responsive problems Css

Tags: css, responsive-design

If we compare  [riste.cf](http://riste.cf/)  and the same site on code pen identical code you get an white banner on the site at riste.ct and not on the codepen one `<a href="https://codepen.io/DrakeApplewood/full/jvMdZz/"> codepen</a>`

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: Can you explain us the problem here?

Comment: Run it on your mobile using Chrome or Firefox and see the problem at riste.cf

Answer (score 0):

If you set your viewport or browser window to about 600px then inspect the project div on the page, you'll see that same elements have a large left-hand margin. This pushes them off the right-hand side of the window and is the root cause of the problem.

For example, #projectsTitle has a margin-left of 18em and #projects has a margin-left of 33em.

I think you want to start by checking details like this. Also, I think it would be safer to change your viewport meta tag from

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Good luck!

Comment: I had the same problem with devices like S7(360px) after resloving it using the same phone have a blank banner like its width overflowing but it`s not